# Convergence of the integral of non negative functions

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-negative continuous functions defined on $[0, 1]$. Assume that $f_n(x) \to f(x$) for every $x \in [0, 1]$. Then if $f_n(x) \leq f(x)$ for every $x \in [0, 1]$, we must have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx =
\int_0^1 f(x) dx$$

I know that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then above result is true?  Is the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly or it can be proved without using the uniform convergence?

Comment: The limit function need not be Riemann integrable. Take $f_n(x)= {1 \over x} 1_{[{1 \over n},1]}(x)$.

Comment: functions are continuous

Comment: A very minor modification of the $f_n$ above will render than continuous an dthe limit is still not Riemann integrable because it is unbounded.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ too? If so, say so.

Comment: In the context of Lebesgue integration the result is true, hence if the limit is Riemann integrable, then the result is true.

Comment: The following is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108619/27978

Comment: Under the hypothesis $\int_0^{1} f(x) \, dx$ need not exist.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/q/108619/27978 doesn't work here as we want $f_n \leq f$ in our case but there the sequence is decreasing.