# Convergence of a series to an integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a real function $f$ bounded continuous on $[0,1]$.

We know that

$$ \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \to \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$$

for $x_i \in [(i-1)/n, i/n]$, as $n\to \infty$.

Now suppose we have a sequence $f_n$ of bounded continuous functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to $f$.

Is it true that

$$ \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f_n(x_i) \to \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$$

Comment: $f$ need not be Riemann-integrable.

Comment: So are you saying that it is true and that $f$ need not to be Riemann-integrable ? Can you provide a proof ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108619/221811 , for example.

Comment: I need a proof of the first statement. The fact that $f$ could be not Riemann-integrable is not of interest here

Comment: Well...is it assumed that $f$ is continuous in the problem?
Notice you merely tell us that the functions in the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are continuous. Perhaps verify that all relevant information from the statement of the problem has been included in your post.

Comment: What do you mean ? It is clearly stated that the $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous.

Comment: @W.Volante: *The fact that f could be not Riemann-integrable is not of interest here* - on the contrary, it proves that the answer to your last question is simply *no* (the RHS might be undefined).

Comment: I guess it is not clear to everyone (clearly more than 1 person) that the function $f$ mentioned at the start of your post is the same $f$ as the pointwise limit $f(x):=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }f_n(x)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Here $f$ is a continuous bounded function on $[0,1]$, so it is Riemann-integrable. I do not care of solving a more general problem.

Comment: In such a case, by considering $f_n-f$, your question can be stated as: is it true that any sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, such that $g_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent to $0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$, is such that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}g_n(x)\,dx = 0$$ ? Unluckily, if the hypothesis of the dominated convergence theorem are not met, the answer still is *not necessarily*. On the other hand, if the $g_n$ are **equi**-bounded, the outcome is positive.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why are you allowed to transform the sum into an integral ? The sum and the function both depend on $n$. I need a justification to split the limits like you did.

Comment: For a fixed $m$ we have that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_m(x_k)$ converges to $\int_{0}^{1}f_m(x)\,dx$ since $f_m(x)$ is continuous, but pointwise convergence and nothing else is not enough to be able to state that $\int_{0}^{1}f_m(x)\,dx \to \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How can you justify that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f_n(x_i) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f_m(x_i)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined on $[0,1]$ that arises by setting $f_1(x)=x$, and for $n=2,3,\ldots$
 \begin{align}f_n(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
                                n^2x , \;  \text{ if } x \in \left[0 , \,\frac{1}{n}\right],  \\
                                   2n - n^2x , \;  \text{ if } x \in \left[\frac{1}{n} , \,\frac{2}{n}\right], \\
    0, \; \text{ if } x \in \left[\frac{2}{n}, \,1\right].\end{cases} 
\end{align}

So for $n=1,2, \ldots$ we have $|f_n(x)| \leq n$, for all $x \in [0,1]$ (each function in the sequence is bounded on $[0,1]$). Moreover, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=0$ and so the pointwise limit is the bounded and continuous function $f(x):=0$ $(x \in [0,1])$. For $n=1,2,...$ let $S_n := \big\{\frac{i}{n} \in [0,1] : i \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$ and for $i=1,\ldots,n$ we allow $x_i \in S_n$ to denote the number $\frac{i}{n}$. Then we have
\begin{equation}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{x_i \in S_n} f_n(x_i) = 1 \;\;\; (n=1,2,\ldots)
\end{equation}
but $\frac{1}{n} \underset{x_i \in S_n}{\sum} f(x_i)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (notice that for $n=2,3,\ldots$ we have $f_n(x_{n-1})=n$ ). In other words, $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \overset{n}{\underset{i =1}\sum} f_n\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) = 1$ (limit of a constant sequence) but $ \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx=0$.

Since this is a counterexample, the statement is not true...

As a bonus:

[image]

Comment: $f_1(x)=1$ is another good choice, call it a matter of preference (value of the integral or definition of a function in the sequence).

Comment: Thank you. If $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, do you think the statement becomes true ?

Comment: Yes it does. For a proof, see Arzelà's Dominated Convergence Theorem for the Riemann Integral here:
https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_15/dominated.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x) = n^2x^n(1-x).$ Then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise everywhere on $[0,1].$ But

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_n(i/n) > \frac{1}{n}f_n((n-1)/n) = \frac{1}{n}n^2(1-1/n)^n\frac{1}{n} \to \frac{1}{e} \ne \int_0^1 0\,dx.$$