# Which of the following imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 f_n(x)dx= \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence of non-negative continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$. Assume that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. which of the following condition imply that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 f_n(x)dx= \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$$
a. $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.
b. $f_n(x) \le f(x)$ for every $x \in [0,1]$
c. $f$ is continuous.

> as i had tried i found a counter example for option(c)and it is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} n^{2}x &\text {if}\:  0 \le x \le 1/n\\ -n^{2}(x-2/n) &\text{if}\;1/n \le x \le 2/n\\ 0 &\text{if}\;  2/n \le x \le 1\end{cases}$$so (c) is not true.
>   for option (a) i used the theorem **Monotone  convergence theorem** so (a) is true but dont know how deal with option (c).

Comment: You need uniform convergence.

Comment: "but don't know how to deal with option (c)". i think you mean (b)

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n(x) \le f(x)$ for each $x$, then $\limsup_n \int f_n(x)dx \le \int f(x)dx$. Since $f_n \to f$, Fatou implies $\liminf_n \int f_n(x)dx \ge \int f(x)dx$. So (b) works.

Comment: Fatou's lemma is applicable only for non-negative functions.

Comment: great! it's applicable

Comment: If $f_n(x)=-n$ for $0<x <\frac 1n$ and $0$ elsewhere then $f=\lim f_n =0$ and  $\int f > \lim \lim \int f_n$. If you claim that non-negativity is not needed in the present problem you have to justify it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i know how to read. what i was trying to tell you is that non-negativity is provided in the problem

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice that the functions were non-negatove. So sorry!.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy no problem. i figured :)

Comment: @mathworker its not given that $f (x)$ is integrable so  how can we integrate $f_n (x) \le f (x) $??

Comment: I don't know what integrating $f_n(x) \le f(x)$ means... Also, you assumed $f$ is integrable for part (a) so I don't know why you're objecting now. In any event, any limit of continuous functions is integrable.

Comment: In part (a) i used monotone convergence theorem which does not use integrability of $f (x) $-@mathworker21

Comment: @sajan like I said before, any limit of continuous functions is integrable, so my solution is correct. Also, monotone convergence theorem and Fatou implicitly use that $f$ is integrable since they talk about $\int f(x)d\mu$!!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108619/pointwise-limit-of-continuous-functions-not-riemann-integrable..can u please see it @mathworker21

Comment: @sajan monotone convergence theorem and Fatou's lemma are for Lebesgue measurability/integrability. If you are using a monotone convergence theorem for Riemann integrability, may you please state exactly what that theorem says?

Comment: @sajan is everything clear now?

Comment: no sir, i was using this theorem https://www.math3ma.com/blog/monotone-convergence-theorem.Ca u please check is it right to apply here??

Comment: @sajan that very clearly says that they are talking about Lebesgue integration. My answer is thus correct and should be accepted.

Comment: @sajan does everything make sense now?