# If $(f_n):[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ are continuous and converge to $f$ pointwise, must $f$ be Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to solve the following question

> True or False? If $(f_n):[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is a sequence of continuous functions which converges to $f$ pointwise, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_0^1{f_n} \to \int_0^1f.$

With help from the comments I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108619/pointwise-limit-of-continuous-functions-not-riemann-integrable) counterexample, but I am hoping there is a simpler one.

If we replace the Riemann integrals by Lebesgue integrals, then the result is true by the Dominated Convergence Theorem. This implies that if $f$ is Riemann Integrable, then indeed  $\int_0^1{f_n} \to \int_0^1f.$ So in looking for a counterexample, we should try to find one where $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108619/732532

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the sequence considered in that question provides a counterexample. However, this is a potential exam problem for me, so I am hoping there is a more elementary counterexample that would be easier to justify on an exam.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my above comment.

Answer (score 3):

The classic counterexample is the following : $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(n!\pi x)^{2m}$. Let $f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(n!\pi x)^{2m}$ (which exists because it is the limit of a positive decreasing sequence), then either there exists $n_0$ such that $f_{n_0}$ is not Riemann-integrable which forms a counterexample because $x\mapsto\cos(n! \pi x)^{2m}$ is Riemann-integrable for all $m$, either the $f_n$ are all Riemann-integrable, but since $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not Riemann-integrable and $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)$, then this is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't it obvious that each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Ruy This is a potential exam question for me, so I think Tuvasbien's argument is a very nice touch, since I will not have to spend time justifying on the exam why $f_n$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Helix, my point is that Tuvasbien's argument does not answer the question because it doesn't provide a sequence of **continuous** functions with the required properties.

Comment: If you want another example, take $$ f_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n!} \delta_{\frac{k}{n!}} $$ where $\delta_y(x)=1$ if $x=y$ and $\delta_y(x)=0$ if $x\neq y$. (They are the same $f_n$ as in my answer).

Comment: $f_n$ is not continuous, as required.  Please check the question's title.

Comment: The OP does not ask for the continuity of $f_n$, but in the title it is said that the $f_n$ have to be continuous...

Comment: @Ruy Yes you are right I did not notice this, thanks for alerting me. Would you know an example with the $f_n$'s being continuous?

Comment: @Tuvasbien I'm sorry for the confusion. I wrote continuous in the title but failed to include it in the question body.

Comment: The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is always continuous in a dense $G_\delta$.  Therefore an example of what you want must necessarily involve a meagre set of positive Lebesgue measure of which the least complicated example is the fat Cantor set appearing in the answer you linked to.  In other words, I doubt one can find a much simpler answer to your question.

Comment: @Ruy Thank you for your reply. By your first statement, do you mean that there exists a dense $G_{\delta}$ set $S$ such that $f$ restricted to $S$ is continuous, or do you mean that the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a dense $G_{\delta}$ set?

Comment: Second alternative.

Comment: See Theorem 1.19 in "Real analysis" by Bruckner, Bruckner and Thomson.